# Checkbox with Twitter Bootstrap for Rails Form Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a rails form using form_tag. How can I add a check box, utilizing twitter bootstrap's styling, and how do I utilize the value? Is it passed in as a param?

My form is something like this:

```
<%= form_tag({action: :import}, multipart: true, class: "form-inline") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:uploaded_file, "Stuff to upload:") %>
  <%= file_field_tag(:uploaded_file, class: "input-file") %>
  <%= submit_tag("Upload", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= button_tag("Cancel", type: 'reset', class: "") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#helpers-for-generating-form-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a check_box_tag like this

```
<%= label_tag :checkbox, "checkbox" %>    
<%= check_box_tag("name", "value", false, class: "checkbox") %>
```

You can set the value to be whatever you want. And assuming you have bootstrap loaded to your app you can just use `class: "checkbox"` and it should appear in the bootstrap styling.

Here's the link to the documentation on the check_box_tag so you can look at it and play around with the settings to get exactly what you are looking for:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I got my checkbox to look Bootstrap-y (Rails 4.2, Bootstrap 3.3) - note that this is inside a `form_for(@model_name) do |f|`, hence the f block variable:

```
  <div class="field form-group">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <%= f.check_box :evac_waiver %>
      <%= f.label :evac_waiver, "Evacuation Waiver signed and accepted" %><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```